# svchos.exe using up almost all my available memory? (Services include wuauserv, Winmgmt, and SENS)

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, memory-leaks

I am new to stackoverflow, and I seem to have a problem with my computer using over 90% of the available memory, even when only Chrome is open.

Here are the symptoms:
When I start my computer, it boots up as usual and everything is fine after I log on for a few minutes. I open Chrome and realize that everything is slow (from loading the page to clicking buttons). I then open task manager (which takes around 15 seconds by itself) and find that the process svchost.exe is using over 75% of my memory, with the total memory usage being at around 90 ~ 95%. I realize that svchost is used to run many things, so I go to services relating to that specific process, and these are the ones running:

[image]

I've looked online and found something about memory leaks or the Alureon virus? I'm not entirely familiar with computers, so I don't really know what they mean. Do I need to get an antivirus or take it to a shop (Canada Computers etc.)?

I'm not sure if these are the specs needed, but I'm running an Acer Aspire M3203 with an AMD Athlon II X3 425 processor, 3 GB of memory and a 64-bit operating system.

It should be noted that after I end the process tree for process, it restarts again **once**. After I end it the second time, it doesn't come up until I restart the computer. Please help ASAP. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the image suppose to show exactly?  I just normal services.

Comment: capture a xperf trace which shows the memory usage GROW/Spikes: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa. But WindowsUpdate is a good candidate. For me it uses over 1GB during scan.

Comment: here I've posted my result in Windows 8: http://superuser.com/a/919777/174557 You can't really fix this. Microsoft must fix this in high memory usgae in the Windows Update DLL

Comment: have you tried the June 2015 WindowsUpdate Client Patch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the services associated to that SvcHost.exe (as highlighted in your screenshot) one at a time until you find the one that is eating your memory.  Based on recent experience, it's most likely Windows Update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I stopped Windows Update first and the memory usage immediately dropped from 89% to 23%. What should I do now? I mean, what is the problem, and do I need professional help for this?

Comment: You could also use Google. ;) Please check(!) whether [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2889748) is applicable for you.

Comment: @Daniel It warns me that I should not install the hotfix for fear of damaging my system if the symptoms are not exactly as described. I don't recall installing Windows Management Framework 3.0 and I can't find it in my installed updates. Should I still continue with the hotfix?

Answer (score 0):

One user reported the [Windows Update Client for Windows 7: June 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265) fixes his memory usage. Make sure that the update is installed and look if it also fixes your issue.