# Why does Windows Update eat up loads of RAM on Win 7 with Server 2008?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, memory, windows-server-2008

We have a lot of Win 7 SP1, both 32 and 64 bit machines serviced by a Server 2008 R2 WSUS server.

For whatever reason, whenever they check for updates, though there aren't any new ones, the PCs end up using all of their available RAM, even 1.3 and 2 GB just for the Windows Update service.

Interestingly enough, this doesn't happen to Windows 8 clients in our environment, they're just fine using only about 100 MB of RAM.

I have come across this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4a782e40-bbd8-40b7-869d-68e3dfd1a5b4/windows-update-scan-high-memory-usage but apparently that only addresses SCCM 2012 which we do not have at the moment.

I know for sure it's the Windows Update service on client machines because I've checked it via perfmon and whenever I stop the service from Task Manager on one of these machines that is checking for updates, about a whole gigabyte of RAM gets freed up.

Does anyone know of any fixes for this?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound this also happens in Windows 8.x (see my picture)

Comment: Hi guys.

This is definitely NOT happening to any of our Windows 8.1 Enterprise clients, only to Windows 7 clients.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265 fixes this, Microsoft finally got their act together.

Comment: FTR: this was the Windows 7 Update client for June 2015, outdated as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this in Windows 8 as you can see in the [xperf Trace I captured and viewed in WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc):

[image]

There is no fix for this because the memory usage comes from the WindowsUpdate client DLL when it scans for Updates (`wuaueng.dll!CAgentUpdateManager::FindUpdates`). The rest of the memory usage comes from loading the Update database `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb` into the RAM.

Comment: Why isn't it affecting the OP's Win8 clients though?

Comment: @Karan this happens when you have installed several additional updates (hotfixes) or other Microsoft Software (Office, Visual Studio, SQL Server).

Comment: Hi guys.

This is definitely NOT happening to any of our Windows 8.1 Enterprise clients, only to Windows 7 clients.

Any ideas?

Comment: I posted a link how to capture and analyze the memory allocations. Look if you see the same like I do in WPA. I talked to Microsoft about it. They know the issue but I have no idea if or when they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In Win 7 SP1 Pro 64-bit, http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265 does **not** fix runaway RAM usage by wuauserv. After the fix has been applied and the PC has rebooted, wuauserv continues to eat 1GB and more of RAM. The service has to be stopped manually, eg find wuauserv in Task Manager/Services and stop the service.

Comment: Turning off windows update it's not a solution, this should only have been posted as a comment, under @Teeest answer.